# Calling a function within a loop?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using the following code:

```
for x in c_body loop

    ln_start := decrypt(card_no); --This calls to a function
    utl_file.put_line(out_file_card, x.data_line); -- writes data to a file
  end loop;
```

I have card_no declared at the top of my procedure, but I have not given it values.
when I try to use a select statement like this one:

```
select card_no_from_table
into card_no
from card_table;
```

It gives me the error that I am trying to insert too many rows into the variable, which I understand. My question therefore, is there a way that I can use the function within the loop?

I thought about having a loop within a loop, or should I try to make a cursor for this?
The reason why I have the function in the loop is, because I need to use the decrypt for every card while it's writing to a file.

Thank you for the help, it's appreciated!

Comment: then use a cursor, and loop into the loop...

Comment: I think you should try to do all this inside your function. Don't try to call a function in a loop. But if you want to do it like this then use cursor. That would be memory efficient as well.

Comment: I'll try the cursor into the loop that Raphael and you(codeBug) suggested, I've been fighting with this for quite a while. I will let you know later today if I had any success with it. Thank you for the help so far.

Comment: use cursor as @RaphaëlAlthaus said: [Working with Cursors](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-mar/o23plsql-1906474.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be better if you use cursor for this.
Try this :

> `CURSOR csr is` `SELECT card_no_from_table FROM card_table;`
>   `rec csr%rowtype;`
>   `BEGIN`
>   `OPEN csr;` 
>   `LOOP`
>   `FETCH csr INTO rec;`
>   `EXIT WHEN csr%NOTFOUND;`
>   `ln_start := decrypt(rec.card_no_from_table);`
>   `utl_file.put_line(out_file_card, x.data_line);`
>   `END LOOP;`
>   `CLOSE csr;`
>   `END;`

Comment: This worked for me, thank you so much for your help as well as the suggestions made by the other members as well. It's highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer that I accepted did solve my problem, but it was quite expensive time wise:
For future reference I will post what I did and what worked for me in this regard.

```
Cursor csr is 
Select name,
       surname,
       decrypt(card_no), -- call the decrypt function in the cursor select
       to_char(sysdate,'DD/MM/YYYY') data_line
From table, followed by where and joins.
```

Then I simply executed the function in the loop to write to the file using this loop:

```
for writeBodyin csr 
loop
    utl_file.put_line(out_file_card, writeBody.data_line);
end loop;
```

and it works wonderfully.